# Code is showing when getting warning about URL shorteners

Tags: bug, status-completed, quality-filter

Recently, I was editing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29722543) and I received a warning about URL shorteners:

[image]

Seems like this is a kind of leak.

Comment: The body *does* contain that text, though...it's blended in nicely with the code.  Not sure what you're expecting; we don't want URL shortener links on the site.  May be appropriate to remove that and replace it with https://www.example.com instead.

Comment: @Makoto what is `/* Controllers\DeveloperController.DataEditor.cs@56 */`? That is what I am expecting! This to be removed

Comment: @Makoto OP is pointing to a source comment that seems to have leaked in the user message. This should not happen.

Comment: That's weird. We're looking into it. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've fixed the error message:

[image: Fixed error message]

Some employees have access to an editor that allows us to edit blacklist error messages, which are stored in the database. In October of 2018 we switched the function used to execute the SQL command upon submit. The new function inserts diagnostic information in the data if it contains a newline. (This is useful for logging purposes, but is obviously not useful in this particular case.) So the immediate solution is to not use newlines in the errors. Since the data is an HTML snippet, we need to use `<br>` tags anyway.

I'm passing this bug on to our developers so that we won't have to worry about making this sort of mistake in the future.